# How to cover negative scenario in the test Methods

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm writing a testClass for a Webservice class. I'm able to cover the positive scenario of the class, but I want to cover Negative scenario also.

As of now only `findErrors` method of `MyGroupHeader` class is getting passed. But I want to cover other 2 classes `finderrors()` also.

```
global class MyGroupHeader {

    webservice String   myGroupDescription;
    webservice List<MyGroupDateRange> dateRangeList;

    public List<String> findErrors() {
        List<String> retval = new List<String>();                           

        if (String.isBlank(this.myGroupDescription)) {
            retval.add('MyGroupHeader.myGroupDescription is NULL.');
        }

        if (this.dateRangeList == null || this.dateRangeList.isEmpty()) {
            retval.add('MyGroupHeader.dateRangeList is NULL or empty.');
        }

        if (this.dateRangeList.size() > 1) {
            retval.add('MyGroupHeader.dateRangeList cannot contain more than one element.');
        }

        return retval;
    }
}


global class MyGroupDateRange {

    webservice Date     effectiveDate;
    webservice Date     endDate;
    webservice List<MyDiscountPercent> discountPercentList;

    public List<String> findErrors() {
        List<String> retval = new List<String>();

        if (this.effectiveDate == null) {
            retval.add('effectiveDate is NULL.');
        }

        if (this.endDate == null) {
            retval.add('endDate is NULL.');
        }

        if (this.discountPercentList == null || this.discountPercentList.isEmpty()) {
            retval.add('discountPercentList is NULL or empty.');
        }

        return retval;
    }

}

global class MyDiscountPercent {
    webservice Decimal  scaledQuantity;
    webservice String   unitOfMeasure;
    webservice Decimal  discountPercent;
    public List<String> findErrors() {
        List<String> retval = new List<String>();

        if (this.scaledQuantity == null) {
            retval.add('scaledQuantity is NULL.');
        }
        if (String.isBlank(this.unitOfMeasure) 
        && this.scaledQuantity != Decimal.valueOf(0)) {
            retval.add('unitOfMeasure is BLANK.');
        }
        if (this.discountPercent == null) {
            retval.add('discountPercent is NULL.');
        }

        return retval;
    }
}

webService static boolean updateMyGroup (MyGroupHeader myGroupInfo) {
    // TO DO Logic
}
```

I have writen testMethods for above apex code. I want to include both positive and negative scenario. Specially `findErrors()` method of each class.

```
@isTest
private class MyServiceTest { 

public static testMethod void testUpdateMyGroupNegative() {
        List<MyService.MyDiscountPercent> pgdpList =  new List<MyService.MyDiscountPercent>();
        MyService.MyDiscountPercent pgdp1 = new MyService.MyDiscountPercent();
        pgdp1.scaledQuantity = null;
        pgdp1.unitOfMeasure = '';
        pgdp1.discountPercent = null;
        pgdpList.add(pgdp1);

        MyService.MyGroupDateRange pgdr1 = new MyService.MyGroupDateRange();
        pgdr1.effectiveDate = null;
        pgdr1.endDate = null;
        pgdr1.discountPercentList = new List<MyService.MyDiscountPercent>();

        MyService.MyGroupHeader pghG5 = new MyService.MyGroupHeader();'';
        pghG5.pricingGroupDescription = '';
        pghG5.dateRangeList = new List<MyService.MyGroupDateRange>();

        MyService.updateMyGroup(pghG5);

     }

     public static testMethod void testUpdateMyGroupPossitive() {
        List<MyService.MyDiscountPercent> pgdpList =  new List<MyService.MyDiscountPercent>();
        MyService.MyDiscountPercent pgdp1 = new MyService.MyDiscountPercent();
        pgdp1.scaledQuantity = 0;
        pgdp1.unitOfMeasure = 'PU';
        pgdp1.discountPercent = -16.67;
        pgdpList.add(pgdp1);

        MyService.MyGroupDateRange pgdr1 = new MyService.MyGroupDateRange();
        pgdr1.effectiveDate = Date.newInstance(2008,12,1);
        pgdr1.endDate = Date.newInstance(9999,12,31);
        pgdr1.discountPercentList = pgdpList;

        MyService.MyGroupHeader pghG5 = new MyService.MyGroupHeader();'';
        pghG5.pricingGroupDescription = 'Fuse';
        pghG5.dateRangeList = new List<ProductService.PricingGroupDateRange>{pgdr1};

        MyService.updateMyGroup(pghG5);

     }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looks like your have added a `findErrors` method to the request objects. Is it your intention is that a caller of your service should always remember to invoke that method and deal with the list of error before they invoke your service? If so, then your tests will have to make that call too before `updateMyGroup` is called for both the passing and failing settings of the data fields on each request object:

```
MyService.MyGroupHeader mgh = new MyService.MyGroupHeader();
System.assertEquals(new Set<String>{
        'MyGroupHeader.myGroupDescription is NULL.',
        'MyGroupHeader.dateRangeList is NULL or empty.',
        'MyGroupHeader.dateRangeList cannot contain more than one element.'
         },
         new Set<String>(mgh.findErrors())
         );
```

Using sets stops the tests from being coupled to the order of the reported errors which is typically a good thing.

If your intention is that the `updateMyGroup` method invokes the `findErrors` method then you will have to change your interface to allow the error detail to be returned.